# What is the correct way to limit windows event log size?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-event-log

I'm looking for a the best way to limit the windows event log size using PowerShell or a command line script. I want to run this script during installation of my application to increase the limit of a log deployed by the installer.

What I've tried thus far is using the limit event log command of power shell `Limit-EventLog -LogName "logName" -MaximumSize xxMB` however this command does not find the log.

Next, I tried using the installer to add the "File" and "MaxSize" registry entries: I created a key matching the event log's name under `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`, a string value with the name 'File', the data, the full path the log file, a dword value with the name 'MaxSize' and the data value in bytes I want to set the max size to be.  This seems to work, however this makes the log show up in a funny way in the event viewer.

[image]

I've also noticed that the maximum log size can be changed directly form the event viewer and this this change isn't reflected in the registry at all. For example the event log "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational" has a limit of 10MB but no corresponding registry entry under 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog'

What I'm looking for is a script that will allow me to obtain the same effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't change the value in the registry, this may lead to unexpected behaviour.

You can use Powershell, but not `Limit-EventLog`, because [the documentation says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Limit-EventLog?view=powershell-5.1) that this works only on classic event logs (before Windows Vista).

> The cmdlets that contain the EventLog noun (the EventLog cmdlets) work
> only on classic event logs. To get events from logs that use the
> Windows Event Log technology in Windows Vista and later versions of
> Windows, use Get-WinEvent.

You can change the event log size by modifying the object that you get with [Get-WinEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics/Get-WinEvent):

```perl
$targetLog = Get-WinEvent -ListLog "Company-Product-Module/Operational"
$targetLog.MaximumSizeInBytes = 2105344
$targetLog.SaveChanges()
```

If you don't know the exact name of the log, you can use `Get-WinEvent -ListLog *` to see them all

Answer (score -1):

You can see and adjust the size of the 'child' event logs (below Application, Security, System etc) in the following registry location:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\<event log name>
```

Change MaxSize to the decimal size in bytes that you want (e.g. 5242880 for 5MB). Apparently it may need to be a multiple of 64KB

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/798940e6-8d11-4a2b-a99a-7dcb3ebf084d/2008-r2-group-policy-settings-for-size-of-application-and-services-logs?forum=winserverGP

https://www.makethenmakeinstall.com/2020/01/increasing-applications-and-services-event-logs-size-with-regedit-and-gpo/